# Copying files from local machine to remote HDFS cluster directly

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, hdfs, cat

I want to copy a file directly from my local Linux machine to a remote HDFS cluster i.e., I don't want to copy the file to the remote machine and then move it to HDFS using copyfromlocal command.

For this, I have executed the following command which I found it in an online blog.

```
cat sample.txt | ssh -tt root@MY_HDFS_CLUSTER "sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put - /user/myuser/data/sample/sample.txt"
```

The issue I am facing while executing the command is that file is copied completely from my local machine to remote HDFS cluster but a file sample.txt.*COPYING* is created in remote HDFS cluster instead of sample.text file. The copy process runs indeterminately, in other words, it is not terminating and I have to kill the process using Ctrl+C.

It is much appreciated if someone help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your sample.txt file? I think it is probably big and the process is not terminating because it hasn't actually finished copying the file yet.